# Cordova: white screen persists on android 5.0(and higher)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, android-5.0-lollipop

I an working with cordova 6 to manually hide the splashscreen with **navigator.splashscreen.hide()**. The app is in angular. It works fine with all android versions below 5.0.

However the white screen persists for **Lollipop** and **Marshmallow**.

Is there an issue with the android APIs for higher versions?

Comment: please list out the which plugin are used to implement splashscreen

Comment: cordova-plugin-splashscreen - 3.2.2, cordova - 6.2.0, cordova-plugin-file - 4.2.0, cordova-plugin-geolocation - 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-whitelist - 1.2.2, cordova-plugin-compat - 1.0.0

Comment: The code works and runs in background. The white screen stays on top of it. If I minimize the app or tap on white screen it goes off. weird !!

Answer (score 2):

Yes,And its not a problem with angular its problem with incompatible versions of plugins and platform for that you need to upgrade your plugin to higher version or keep your platform to lower version. And main dependency thing in cordova is if you want to update your platform you need update npm first, if you want to update your npm you need to update node.js first.